# How do you create a loop to calculate the mean of a given column?

Tags: python

I am having trouble with just basic summary statistics in Python. This is my portion of the dataset and how I'm trying to write a function called print_mean() that will calculate and print the mean value of a given column in the dataset. This is what I have so far but the program I'm using says there's errors -

```
oscar_data = [
 ["Driving Miss Daisy", 1989, 7.645, 99, ['drama'], 7.5, 145.793296],
 ["Rain Man", 1988, 8.25, 133, ['drama'], 25.0, 354.825435],
]

def print_mean(data, column):
    total = 0
    for row in data:
        total += sum(row)
    mean = total / len(data)
    print('{:.2f}'.format(mean))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data entry will be a list of lists, I suggest you to do:

```py
# Column will begin with 0

def print_mean(data, column):
    total = 0.0
    for row in data:
        total += row[column]
    mean = total / len(data)
    print('{:.2f}'.format(mean))
```

Maybe that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

A concise approach using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) is:

```
def mean(data, column):
    return sum(row[column] for row in data) / len(data)

print(mean(oscar_data, 1))
```